# How to limit overflowing of text in mobile devices? - CSS

Tags: css, sass

I have a situation wherein I have a very long string say
"123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789"

Now, I want to display the string with even number of characters but in different line, as for mobile screens, it overflows.
For ex,
123456789
123456789
123456789
and so on.

Please help with the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: CSS is content unaware and cannot do this. You'll need to use JavaScript or something else to read the characters and then create a line break.

Comment: If I limit the width to 200px and then try to adjust in that, is there a way?

Comment: You could use `max-width: 9ch` but it would only work if you are uings a monospaced font

Comment: No, there is no way CSS can do this unless you know the specific width of each `123456789`, then you can possibly do `overflow-wrap: break-word;` however, it will not specifically break at `123456789`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-width` property.

```css
p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 9ch;
}
```

```html
<p>123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789</p>
```